# Mysterious bottom padding in CSS

Tags: css

Please see [here](http://www.mossoreviews.com/57-nikon-d5100-16-2mp-cmos-digital-slr-camera-review/), at the end of the post, the 70px author image from gravatar.com is having a mysterious bottom padding, making the bottom padding a lot more wider than the top, left and right ones.

I looked all 3 browsers, FF11, Chrome and IE9 and all are presenting the same problem. I couldn't find the culprit with Firebug. The extra *padding* is no padding nor margin of anything!

Any idea?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set a `height` to the Gravatar wrapper `div` - http://jsfiddle.net/AMf5N/1/

```
#post-author .profile-image {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F6F6F6;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    float: left;
    height: 70px; /* add this */
    margin: 0 15px 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

or `float` the image - http://jsfiddle.net/AMf5N/

Comment: Whilst this works, it is more of a hack than a solution. For instance, if the image height was to change, the parent wouldn't change accordingly.

Comment: @joshnh Did you see the 2nd part of the answer with the `float`? It will work on image of any size. So the OP can choose whichever suites his needs best.

Comment: I did. You're still better off addressing the actual issue instead of removing the image from the flow of the document as a work around though. Both of your options work, but neither of them deal with the actual problem, and both of them have the potential to cause other issues.

Comment: @joshnh usually the whole web development is about workarounds to make the website work in all browsers. And ANY line of code you write has the potential to cause other issues :) So if you have a better solution then please share it - I'm really open to new stuff and have learned a lot on SO already. People sometimes have extremely neat solutions to trivial problems.

Comment: All thanks to @ZoltanToth! I've been crunching for 9 weeks and can't see straight, this kept me from weepeing